# Why does my all badges and reputation lost when I logged in?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, login, user-accounts

Lastday, I had logged-in on stackoverflow, it asked to create and associate accounts. Although I have used same credentials to login. I was in doubt so I clicked on'Create and link' button. But what happen next is frustrating for me. I have lost my reputation and badges, although all questions and comments are there, which I have asked. When I checked question, it shows that question asked by **'user3291673'**. But this account is not accessible.

Please help

Comment: [There's no such user with id 3291673](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3291673). You must have had your account removed.

Answer (score 29):

I deleted your account on November 21. You and several others all clearly conspired to defraud the voting system by participating in a voting ring that was propping up low-quality or incorrect content. This voting coordination came to the attention of moderators through community flags or through our standard tools.

As your account had contributed little of value beyond the coordinated voting, I felt it safe to delete it in order to invalidate these votes. The friends of yours with more significant contributions were strongly warned about this and their votes manually invalidated by Stack Exchange employees.

In the future, I highly recommend not coordinating votes between yourself and your friends in an effort to gain an unfair advantage over others.

Comment: But I asked genuine questions and have answers from you guys. It is not fare. I have strong feeling that this platform is full of Good people but such behavior is not good as I am learning the system. You can warned me, if I am doing anything wrong as some people did on my wrong questions. I don't know what is the wrong with liking the questions from other people but Sorry to say deleting an entire account is not good for any forum.

Comment: @GauravRajput no point trying to hide your mistakes under cover of innocence. Really. Be thankful you were able to create new account and that it's not deleted on spot, and I hope you won't try to perform further vote fraud.

Comment: I am not hiding anything. I am just saying it may be by mistake, @Brad also said, my part is very little. I will be very happy if He removed only votes and give me warning about what I am doing wrong. that's all I want to say only. Even I am happy that people on the forum monitor such things. My only concern is about the deletion of the complete account. Because I am here for learning, not for votes and I can learn without creating account.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the time you gave to clarify the things, it would be helpful for me to keep my account clean :) :) :)